# How to add members to Multi-User Chat Subscriptions like whatsapp using Admin Rest API

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am trying to create a chat application exactly like WhatsApp using Ejabberd server. I successfully create groups using admin APIs. But I can't add members to it. below is the request format.
http://ejabberd.mysite.com:5281/api/create_room

```
 {
  "name": "roomAndroidTest3",
  "service": "conference.mysite.com",
  "host": "ejabberd.mysite.com",
   "options": [
    {
      "name": "members_only",
      "value": "true"
    },
     {
      "name": "allow_subscription",
      "value": "true"
    }

  ]
}
```

How can I **add/delete** members to this group? I don't find any rest API for this. I know how to add using subscription methods. But I want my server admin to handle all this functionality.

If this is not the right way, Please tell me how WhatsApp handling this functionality?

Already read these docs [muc-pub](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/), but not helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I add/delete members to this group?

You can grant "member" affiliation with:

https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#set-room-affiliation

For example, grant member:

> $ ejabberdctl set_room_affiliation sala1 conference.localhost user881@localhost member

Revoke member:

> $ ejabberdctl set_room_affiliation sala1 conference.localhost user881@localhost none

Comment: so if I can use /api/set_room_affiliation to add a member then how can I remove him?